# .htaccess rewrite with long query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to get this to work for the past day, this part(/order.php?id=) has to equal what (shopping_basket.ws=)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
# Turn mod_rewrite on 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mod=shirt-appeal&ssl=1&expired=1&dest=shopping_basket.ws=([0-9]*)$

RewriteRule ^m=shop/shopform.ws?$ /order.php?id=%1  [NC,L]
```

Example of url: www.domain.com/m=shop/shopform.ws?mod=shirt-appeal&ssl=1&expired=1&dest=shopping_basket.ws=100

Comment: Your rule works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine for me too.